# Composite foreign key symfony2 yml

Tags: symfony, model, doctrine, foreign-keys

I'm try to have the right solution to generate my entities From yml in symfony2.

here is the part of the code in YML:

```
  oneToMany:
    actions:
      targetEntity: Action
      mappedBy: testcaseid
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And i'm searching for a way to put a composite key in it like maybe

```
mappedBy:testcaseid,revision
```

But it doesn't work for now and i dont' have the right syntaxe and can't find it on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact i just found the answer myself.

composite pk are generated on the manyToOne side.

Another issue you might have with doctrine is the generation of the crud with composite keys...